# Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.17\hostpolicy.dll]

Tags: .net, .net-core, apple-m1, visual-studio-2022, parallels

I am running a Parallels Win11 VM (M1 Pro), Visual Studio 2022, .NET 5.0

When trying to run the basic hello world template application, I get:

> Failed to load the dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.17\hostpolicy.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
> An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.17]

> C:\Development\Demo\DemoApp\bin\Debug\net5.0\DemoApp.exe (process 6136) exited with code -2147450750.
> To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
> Press any key to close this window . . .

The folder and file are there and accessible. I have tried changing the permissions on the folder. But that had no effect.

I am new to .NET, help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Happens when a .net program that's forced to run in 32-bit mode tries to load the 64-bit version of the .net runtime.  Perhaps the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable is not set correctly.

Comment: Any fixes already? I'm struggeling with exactly the same problem.